# Load content using ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to ajax.

I have **index.html**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"n.php",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>

<div id="div1" style="margin-left: 25;"></div>
<button>Add Author</button>
```

**n.php**

```
Name:<input type="text" name="txtname">
age:<input type="text" name="txtage">
```

Simply i want to add name and age textboxes on index.html page when 'Add Author' button clicks without refreshing page.But above code loads name and age textboxes only once.I want it every time when button clicks.

**Edit:**

Now if I want to put another button 'remove author',and want to perform exact opposite action(i.e) remove both textboxes.what should i do? can u please help?

and want to know how can i check validation server side?

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$("#div1").html(result);
```

to

```
$("#div1").append(result);
```

So everytime you click the button it will append the textboxes.

Comment: Now if I want to put another button 'remove author',and want to perform exact opposite action(i.e) remove both textboxes.what should i do? can u please help?

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"n.php",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").append(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
```

use `append` instead of `html`. `append` will add the response at the end of whatever content is present in the div wherease `html` will replace the present content.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"n.php",success:function(result){
  $("#div1").append(result);
   }});
   });
  });
  </script>

    <div id="div1" style="margin-left: 25;"></div>
    <button>Add Author</button>
```